# How do I add the GNOME logo in the corner of the screen?

Tags: gnome-classic

[image]

[image]

I miss the old GNOME foot in the top left corner of the screen (missing in first photo, present in the second) - how can I put it back?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

Comment: The seconds screenshot it's not a theme it looks like Awesome WM.

Comment: @UriHerrera Not a dupe, already on GNOME Classic. Also, what WM does Ubuntu 11.10 normally have?

Comment: @UriHerrera installed AwesomeWM, not quite what I expected. See edit.

Comment: Change the distributor logo, Those are tiled terminal windows, doing "stuff", Ubuntu uses Metacity.

Comment: @UriHerrera how do I change the logo?

Comment: @UriHerrera and make the other changes to mirror that image?

Comment: The second image as you may not know is Gnome 2, while you can't make it look exactly like that anymore, the other question i put in the comments leaves you with the closest possible, also in the image the user is using the global menu (appmenu now) so add the proper extension, there's too a gnome shell extension to add the logo there, and to have that all terminal look, stop using GUI software, and use the terminal for everything.

Comment: @UriHerrera will check that out later.

Comment: @UriHerrera...could I install GNOME 2?

Comment: No, it conflicts with Gnome 3-

Comment: @UriHerrera can I uninstall GNOME 3 and then install GNOME 2?

Comment: @tekknolagi - please ask one question at a time - I've edited your question to reflect your first question in the title.

Comment: @fossfreedom i feel like people would get annoyed if i asked repeated questions about this

Comment: ... if people were annoyed they would down-vote the question!  Since you've got a couple of upvotes - people think its a good question.  Carry on asking good questions :)

Comment: @fossfreedom point. will do, señor!

Answer (score 2):

The Gnome-Panel used in Oneiric uses a slightly different key-combination to add/delete and move options:

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and right-click the top menu bar - N.B. <kbd>Win</kbd> is the Windows Symbol key

If you are using Gnome Classic (No Effects) i.e. *gnome fallback mode* then to add to the panel use <kbd>Alt</kbd> and right-click)

Make sure you right-click over the menu itself - you will have two options: Move and Delete.  Delete the menu.

Repeat the key-mouse combination.  This time:

[image]

Choose the *Add to Panel*

Scroll down the list - you will see two *Menu* options

- Custom Main Menu
- Main Menu

Choose one of these options for the style of menu you want.

---

Linked Question

1. [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)